# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '`${any}`' can't be used to index type

Tags: typescript

I missed out something here using Typescript I need help

```
   const onClick = (name: string) => {
      dialogFuncMap[`${name}`](true);
    };

    const onHide = (name: string) => {
      dialogFuncMap[`${name}:any`](false);
    };
```

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing, *as plain text in the body of your post*. Ideally I could paste such code into a standalone IDE and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values. (If you want to provide a [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wRG7YN) that's great, but please also put the full example *in the body of the post as text*.)

Comment: Would you please show us the definition of `dialogFuncMap` and also where is `name` coming from? Looks like `dialogFuncMap` definition doesn't allow indexed access.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

The following should work. The key is to declare `name` as the keys of `dialogFuncMap` instead of just `string`. This is because the type associated with `dialogFuncMap` has predefined indexes and their type should be the same. Notice now `name` is declared as `name: DialogFuncMapKeys`.

```js
const hello = (value: boolean) => console.log('hello')
const world = (value: boolean) => console.log('world')

const dialogFuncMap = {
  hello: hello,
  world: world,
}

type DialogFuncMapKeys = keyof typeof dialogFuncMap // <- Here

const onClick = (name: DialogFuncMapKeys) => { // <- Here
  dialogFuncMap[`${name}`](true)
}

const onHide = (name: DialogFuncMapKeys) => { // <- Here
  dialogFuncMap[`${name}`](false)
}

onClick('hello')
onHide('world')
```

### Solution 2

Another solution is to declare the `dialogFuncMap` keys themselves type as `string` like `Record<string, (value: boolean) => void>`. Take a look below:

```js
const hello = (value: boolean) => console.log('hello')
const world = (value: boolean) => console.log('world')

const dialogFuncMap: Record<string, (value: boolean) => void> = { // <- Here
  hello: hello,
  world: world,
}

const onClick = (name: string) => {
  dialogFuncMap[`${name}`](true)
}

const onHide = (name: string) => {
  dialogFuncMap[`${name}`](false)
}

onClick('hello')
onHide('world')
```